# Sharepoint UpdateListItems list not updating

Tags: c#, sharepoint, moss, wss

I submit an update to UpdateListItems. It returns success but the list item ahs not updated. Any advice on how I would track down what is going wrong?

Below is the XML being generated:

```
<Batch OnError='Continue' ListVersion='1' ViewName=''>
   <Method ID='1' Cmd='Update'>
      <Field Name='ID'>11707</Field>
      <Field Name='Business_x0020_Area'>Consumer</Field>
      <Field Name='Team'>6;#IT Support</Field>
      <Field Name='Job_x0020_Number'>TEMP</Field>
      <Field Name='Media_x0020_Outlet2'>13;#BBC Parliament</Field>
      <Field Name='Publication_x0020_Date'>2009-09-01 14:40:10</Field>
      <Field Name='Narrative2'></Field>
      <Field Name='Page_x0020_Number'>1</Field>
      <Field Name='Media_x0020_Value'></Field>
      <Field Name='Information_x0020_Only'>0</Field>
      <Field Name='Date_x0020_Added'></Field>
   </Method>
</Batch>
```

**Update**

The error I am getting in U2U is

0x81020014 One or more field types are not installed properly. Go to the list settings page to delete these fields.

Comment: Could you post a code snippet?

Comment: Are you using C# to process the batch? Are you using the "ProcessBatchData" function? If you are, what is the result string?

Comment: I am just using the UpdateListItems method in lists.asmx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had an internal field in the CAML that was not in the database. This was causing it to trip up.

Answer (score 1):

My first suggestion is keeping field names as they are such as 'Business Area' instead of  'Business_x0020_Area'. I know when when you look up the list xml file, field names are shown like that. The second suggestion is about your date field. Make sure your date is constructed properly. The date field format is YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SSZ. The T and Z are important. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

The 401 is indicating that you are not logged in, or the user who you are logged in as does not have permissions on that list. Verify that the user 'executing' the batch script can log in to the site and make changes to the list.

Comment: This problem was because I was trying to update a list on a server outside the domain. On the same server as share point it would allow me to update.

Comment: Cool! Thanks for the update. You should add your own answer to the question. Either edit it into the question itself, click "post an answer" at the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

I've made something like this for the date

```
public DateTime dateForSp(string s)
{
    string[] sd = s.Split('/');
    string[] yd = sd[2].Split(' ');
    string[] hd = yd[1].Split(':');

    DateTime dt = new DateTime(Int32.Parse(yd[0]),
                               Int32.Parse(sd[0]),
                               Int32.Parse(sd[1]),
                               Int32.Parse(hd[0]),
                               Int32.Parse(hd[1]),
                               Int32.Parse(hd[2]));

    return dt;
}
```

and in the code

```
"<Field Name='SubmissionTime'>" + String.Format("{0:u}", dateForSp(this.rProperty["SubmissionTime"])) + "</Field>"
```